# Mechanism of the Gatterman Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-reduction

Aryl diazonium salt on treatment with copper and the corresponding hydrohalic acid, gives the aryl halide. This reaction is called the Gatterman reaction.

What is the mechanism of this reaction? Is it similar to Sandmeyer reaction?

Comment: That's not the Gatterman reaction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gattermann_reaction

Comment: Have you Googled this? I think you have described the Sandmeyer rxn.

Comment: @Zhe Indeed that is the more famous Gattermann reaction. The Wikipedia link that you have provided also contains a link to the Gatterman reaction I am referring to right at the top of the page.

Comment: @user55119 No, the reagent used in Sandmeyer reaction is cuprous halide. March's Advanced Organic Chemistry specifically mentions Gatterman reaction as an alternative to Sandmeyer reaction.

Comment: March notwithstanding, the Sandmeyer rxn is an improvement on the Gattermann conditions that uses mineral acid (HCl, HBr) and copper salts in the second step. The Sandmeyer rxn uses only CuX. This version of the "Gattermann rxn" is lost to history. The Gattermann and Gattermann-Koch reactions are methods for formylating aromatic rings in the absence of diazonium salt.

Comment: @user55119 Thank you, I wasn't aware of this. Does this mean that the 'obsolete' Gattermann reaction doesn't have any accepted mechanism? Would you please suggest a probable mechanism anyway?

Comment: It's probably $\mathrm{S}_{N}\mathrm{Ar}$.

Comment: Listen to @Zhe!

Comment: @Zhe But, what will be the nucleophile? Also, can we rule out the possibility of an aryl radical intermediate which is formed in the Sandmeyer reaction?

Comment: @Zhe Hey, I just found this - https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470638859.conrr265 while I was googling the reaction. Unfortunately, I can't access these papers. If you can, would you check if it talks about any mechanism? Thanks

Comment: I can't access it, but a radical pathway is probably the only other reasonable thing to consider. And frankly, if the paper can substantiate it, it is radical, at least under their conditions.

Comment: @Zhe Thanks a lot for your help. Hopefully, someone who can access it will see this question :)

Comment: The reference for the Kochi paper is DOI: 10.1021/ja01568a066

Answer (score -1):

The Gattermann reaction you mentioned in the question uses Copper powder and Hydrohalous acid to substitute diazonium group with a halide in an aromatic diazonium salt.
It uses **$ArSN_1$**  pathway, similar to Sandmeyer Reaction which uses Copper Halide and corresponding Hydrohalous acid instead of copper powder.
As diazonium group is a very good leaving group, it departs leading to a phenyl carbocation which is very unstable, this is in fact the slow step of the reaction. 
The Nucleophile (Halide in this case) attacks the phenyl carbocation leading to the formation of Halobenzene(fast step).
Nitrogen gas and Hydrogen chloride are also formed.

Comment: Can you tell me the source of this information?

Comment: It's what our teacher taught us in the class. @AnubhabDas